# PySpark S3 Internal S3 (jupyter notebook) - Error - Name or service not known

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using internal S3 ( western digital) to store json files. 
Trying to read json file via Pyspark in jupyter lab.I am new to spark. Please guide

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4 pyspark-shell"
# pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2
import findspark
findspark.init('/root/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import configparser



hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
myAccessKey = '*************'
mySecretKey = '******'
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "https://abc.domain.com")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)

df = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://bucketname/filename.json")
df.show()
```

- Am I passing bucket name incorrectly as I see url failed for this.

**com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: bucketname.abc.domain.com:: Name or service not known**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-02e7cddb8018> in <module>
     89 # df.show()
     90 
---> 91 df = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://bucketname/test_sjc.json")
     92 df.show()
     93 # s3_resource.Object(s3_bucket, first_file_name).download_file(

~/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding, locale)
    271             path = [path]
    272         if type(path) == list:
--> 273             return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    274         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    275             def func(iterator):

~/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1284         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1285         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1286             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1287 
   1288         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o196.json.
: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: bucketname.abc.domain.com:: Name or service not known
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:454)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.FileDataSourceV2.qualifiedPathName(FileDataSourceV2.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.FileDataSourceV2.$anonfun$getTableName$1(FileDataSourceV2.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.FileDataSourceV2.getTableName(FileDataSourceV2.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.FileDataSourceV2.getTableName$(FileDataSourceV2.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.json.JsonDataSourceV2.getTableName(JsonDataSourceV2.scala:26)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.json.JsonDataSourceV2.getTable(JsonDataSourceV2.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:220)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:411)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bucketname.abc.domain.com: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with something similar recently:
Try adding the following lines to the hadoop configuration:

```
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true");
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false");
```

Might sort out this error.
Hope it helps!